# through Webclient how to list?

Tags: string, vb.net, list, download

Very simple I believe just can't get it myself

I'm taking a string example "88888<>88888<>88888<>" and all I want to do is remove the "<>" take the part after and place on 2nd line of a list so it would become

1. 88888
2. 88888
3. 88888

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and spend some time clearly explaining the problem.  Include the code you have now and how it doesnt work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the work for you using `.IndexOf()` and `.SubString()`. There are other shorter ways too, a lot more actually but I wrote this so you can know what's happening in every step and know the exact solution.

```
    Dim FInalString As String
    Dim String_ As String = "88888<>8888888<>88888<>"
    'now find the position of first <>
    Dim firstsign_ As Integer = String_.IndexOf("<", 0)
    'add string upto that point in the textbox
    FInalString = "1. " & String_.Substring(0, firstsign_)
    'now find the position of second <>
    Dim secondSign_ As Integer = String_.IndexOf("<", firstsign_ + 2) 'here, not 0 because we have to skip the first one
    ' MsgBox(secondSign_)
    'add the string upto that point in the textbox
    FInalString = FInalString & vbCrLf & "2. " & String_.Substring(firstsign_ + 2, secondSign_ - firstsign_ - 2) 'vbCrLf means go to next line now
    'now find the third sign, last 
    Dim lastsign_ As Integer = String_.IndexOf("<", secondSign_ + 2)
    'add to the string 
    FInalString = FInalString & vbCrLf & "3. " & String_.Substring(secondSign_ + 2, lastsign_ - secondSign_ - 2)

    MsgBox(FInalString)
```

Output:

> 1. 88888
> 2. 8888888
> 3. 88888

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this has to do with a WebClient. But this should work as you need.

```
    Dim str As String = "88888<>88888<>88888<>"
    Dim strarr As String() = str.Split("<>")
    Dim result As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To strarr.Length
        result &= (i + 1) & ". " & strarr(i)
    Next
```